# Why are x64 merge module files not included in msi file

Tags: wix, wix3.6

My first WIX installer (I have InstallShield experience).  I have included this merge module...

```
Merge Id="CRT" Language="0" SourceFile="$(env.LIBRARY_ROOT)\microsoft-merge-modules\vs2010-sp1\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm" DiskId='1'
```

The media is as follows...

```
Media Id='1' Cabinet='product.cab' CompressionLevel='high' EmbedCab='yes'
```

I open the MSI file in ORCA and see the two mscv... files listed in the components table, but the Visual Studio 2010 build of the installer solution (besides creating the msi file), also creates a WIN\SYSTEM64 folder which contains the two files (`msvcr100.dll` and `msvcp100.dll`).

When I run the installer on my test system, (if I do no also bring over the Win folder), I get "error reading from the file: `c:\lou\win\system32\msvcp100.dll`".

I then added another product merge module that I had created myself, again, those files (which are being installed to ProgramFilesx64), are not in the msi, but are in a seperate folder 'Program Files 64\productfolder' that needs to be copied to the target system.

Why are these files not included in the MSI file?

Comment: Try to format your question a little bit

Comment: I have no idea of what you are talking about.  How about some specifics as I am new to this.

Comment: Where is there a link to tell me what this 'Votes', etc, is all about?

Comment: Are you building your MSI as x86 or x64?

Comment: In VS 2010, the Configuration is Active(Release), and the Platform is Active(x64).  In the wxs file the Package is Platform="x64".  This is the same for both the main installer and the merge module.

Comment: Perhaps I did not phrase the question correctly.  The installer works correctly (if I bring over the files and folders that were not included in the MSI file)...the files are installed to where they should be.  The question is...why are these folders and files excluded from the MSI file and put in seperate folders that (in addition to the msi file), need to be included in the install media?

Answer (score 0):

From the WIX documentation, a description of the Compression attribute on the Package element:

Compressed YesNoDefaultType Whether the package payload should be embedded in a container or left as an external payload.